# Attachment entity without body tag

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-365

> Issue : I am using email attachment entity to receive email with attachments.
>   Our environment is - D365. When Email is sent using outlook or d365 as well, the attachment entity is without body tag

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create attachment locally (can be any extension or encoding)
2. Send email either to account synced with D365 or use D365 to send email to same along with attachment.
3. query email with attachments and also get body tag

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" >
    <entity name="email" >
        <attribute name="modifiedon" />
        <attribute name="sender" />
        <order attribute="modifiedon" descending="false" />
        <filter>
            <condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="on-or-after" value="2020-03-25" />
        </filter>
        <link-entity name="activitymimeattachment" from="objectid" to="activityid" link-type="inner" alias="ak" >
            <attribute name="filename" />
            <attribute name="body" />
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

o   Expected output.

```
<resultset morerecords="0">
  <result>
    <modifiedon date="3/27/2020" time="3:08 PM">2020-03-27T15:08:54+05:30</modifiedon>
    <sender> xyz@abc.com</sender>
    <ak.filename>test-20181009T133141.xml</ak.filename>
    <ak.body>VGhlIFVSTCBzaG91bGQgYmUgY29udmVydGVkIHRvIEJhc2U2NA==</ak.body>
  </result>
</resultset>
```

•

o   Received output.

```
<resultset morerecords="0">
  <result>
    <modifiedon date="3/27/2020" time="4:04 PM">2020-03-27T16:04:24+05:30</modifiedon>
    <sender>xyz@abc.com</sender>
    <ak.filename>test-2019-04-17T200954.660.xml</ak.filename>
  </result>
  <result>
    <modifiedon date="3/27/2020" time="4:12 PM">2020-03-27T16:12:15+05:30</modifiedon>
    <sender> xyz@abc.com</sender>
    <ak.filename>image002.jpg</ak.filename>
  </result>
  <result>
    <modifiedon date="3/27/2020" time="4:12 PM">2020-03-27T16:12:15+05:30</modifiedon>
    <sender> xyz@abc.com</sender>
    <ak.filename>image004.jpg</ak.filename>
  </result>
  <result>
    <modifiedon date="3/27/2020" time="4:12 PM">2020-03-27T16:12:15+05:30</modifiedon>
    <sender> xyz@abc.com</sender>
    <ak.filename>image006.jpg</ak.filename>
  </result>
</resultset>
```

Please help us in finding the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove  `distinct="true"`  form your fetchxml and then it shall work.

Try below fetchxml

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" >
    <entity name="email" >
        <attribute name="modifiedon" />
        <attribute name="sender" />
        <order attribute="modifiedon" descending="false" />
        <filter>
            <condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="on-or-after" value="2020-03-25" />
        </filter>
        <link-entity name="activitymimeattachment" from="objectid" to="activityid" link-type="inner" alias="ak" >
            <attribute name="filename" />
            <attribute name="body" />
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Well I checked in My Fetchxml Builder and it does return me body. What do you get?